# Can I add GitHub as debugger source in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, github, nuget

I am using some NuGet packages in my projects which have their source publicly available in GitHub (example [OrmLite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite)).

How can I configure their repositories as debugger sources in Visual Studio (the same way I could configure ReferenceSource for the .NET Framework etc... [like here](https://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Wiki/Using))?

ReSharper is able to decompile the DLLs, but I am more interested in seeing the comments which are obviously not available this way.

**Update:**

I know about the `pdb` files, but the initial intension was to see the source code when I hit <kbd>F12</kbd>. For the .NET Framework that is acheived by simply adding the ReferenceSource as I explained before

Comment: The problem is you are missing a important 2nd peice besides the code, the `pdb` file. Without it you will not likely be able to associate source with code. Most NuGet packages do not bundle the pdb with the package.

Comment: Please see updated question

Comment: The problem is when you add the RefrenceSource, **it downloads pdb files**, that is how it knows what code it goes to when you hit F12. No pdb, no detailed info when you hit F12.

Answer (score 9):

What you are looking for is http://symbolsource.org, which is a platform for hosting open source pdb (debugging) files.

To use it, you'll need to update your Visual Studio instance to pull pdb's from there (http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Home/VisualStudio):

> 1. Go to Tools -> Options -> Debugger -> General.
>
>    2. Uncheck “Enable Just My Code (Managed only)”.
>    3. Uncheck “Enable .NET Framework source stepping”. Yes, it is misleading, but if you don't, then Visual Studio will ignore your custom server order (see further on).
>    4. Check “Enable source server support”.
>    5. Uncheck “Require source files to exactly match the original version”
>    6. Go to Tools -> Options -> Debugger -> Symbols.
>    7. Select a folder for the local symbol/source cache.
>    8. Add symbol servers under “Symbol file (.pdb) locations”. Pay attention to the correct order, because some servers may contain symbols for the same binaries: with or without sources. We recommend the following setup:
>
>       - http://referencesource.microsoft.com/symbols
>       - http://srv.symbolsource.org/pdb/Public or the authenticated variant (see above)
>       - http://srv.symbolsource.org/pdb/MyGet or the authenticated variant (see above)
>       - (other symbol servers with sources)
>       - http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
>       - (other symbol servers without sources)

**Note:** Not every nuget package also uploads symbols to SymbolSource (as it requires an additional publishing step).  So you might need to contact the developer of the project and ask them to upload it, or if the project is open source, you could do it yourself.

Comment: I did these steps before and already and I mentioned the link in my question. Not what I need. I am looking for any way we dont know to skip the extra steps and get the source directly from GitHub

Comment: Then no, I don't think GitHub does not expose a symbol source consumable by Visual Studio.  That's why you'll need to use an intermediary like Symbol Server.

Comment: http://symbolsource.org/ gives me a rude ASP.NET default error page at the moment and status 500.

Comment: http://symbolsource.org/ is currently dead, domain name isn't registered :-/ are there any new alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

Use the original source-code from GitHub by download the relevant VS code projects and add them to your solution for references instead of using the binaries.

Comment: Then I will no longer be using NuGet... and I will lose all of NuGet advantages..

Comment: read this article: http://nikcodes.com/2013/10/23/packaging-source-code-with-nuget/